# What is _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY?

Tags: c-preprocessor, inline, libc++

The LLVM libc++ headers have a macro, used in function declarations, named `_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY`.

I don't understand what it means; I looked at its definition, and it says:

```
// Just so we can migrate to the new macros gradually.
#define _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_HIDE_FROM_ABI
```

... and this second macro has no definition I can find. So, what does `_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY` mean and what is it typically expanded into?

Comment: Introduced [here](https://reviews.llvm.org/D49240).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Thanks, @Ruslan)

The intent is to hide functions marked with it from appearing in dynamic libraries ("hide from the ABI"). This used to be done by making such functions `inline` only, but now, the clang attribute `attribute((internal_linkage))` is used; that's the definition of `_LIBCPP_HIDE_FROM_ABI`.

As for the inline-for-invisibility macro `_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY` - what you're seeing is it being redefined to what its name *should have been* to being with.